# Of course, *I* could solve this easily

Tags: cipher

Question:
What do you think about music?
Encoded below is part of one of my favorite songs.
Rejoice, as the key to decrypt it is a common pattern.
The type of thing you might see everyday.
You should add on and on with a space at the end.

9 7 11 19 17 22 9 14 8 24 7 15 16 22 20 9 14 5 4 18 24 6 24 16 18 19 25 22 11 24 2 14 14 22 2 6 3 25 24 26 24 10 20 1 10 16 19 10 22 8 17 2 3 20 7 1 2 21 2 9 22

Continuing:

> 21 8 19 22 16 14 7 22 2 9 24 24 22 5 4 18 19 17 27 9 9 8 17 2 5 11 14 24 26 9 23 27 5 22
>  I didn't want to make this too long originally, but it does have a feature that hints at the same thing as the 6th line.

Source: me, failing to fall asleep at night.

Comment: If you want a hint, here's something I've noticed. rot13(Ybbx ng gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu yvar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> OH LORD IT'S HARD TO BE HUMBLE

First thing I noticed:

> The words QWERTY, key, type, space point at a qwerty keyboard and indicate that the numbers possibly represent letters in the order in which they appear on a keyboard. The translation is then OUALJCOFIBUGHCZOFTRKBYBHKLNCABWFFCWYENBMBPZQPHLPCIJWEZUQWXWOC.

Then I tried

> Literally all Caesar ciphers, Vigenere with the key QWERTY, and since the title says that the OP could solve it, Vigenere with the key TED. None of it gave anything readable.

Only then I realized

> **You should add on and on...** Of course: the first 9 indicates the ninth letter on the keyboard; but then the 7 indicates that you should keep going from that 9, 7 steps ahead. That clue wasn't there at the beginning, I'd actually thought it could be that but was too lazy to try.

Comment: That's it! Good job!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was:

> these are letters of the alphabet as there are none over 26, but that gives you:
>  R T P H J E R M S C T L K E G R M V W I C U C K I H B E P C Y M M E Y U X B C A C Q G Z Q K H Q E S J Y X G T Z Y F Y R E
>  which doesn't mean much even if you ROT13

So I'm not much further along. Although I did think possibly:

> the mention of a key means possibly a vignere cypher?? but I couldn't get anything useful out of that :( (or rather come up with the answer to the riddle posed about what the key might be)

Comment: You're on the right track, and that word is indeed a hint at something, but not quite what you were thinking of.